# Linear differential equations system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was confronted with the following problem on my mid-term paper and I've got no idea how to solve this, I tried using the eigenvalues method, but it ultimately failed . Can anyone, please, give a complete solution to this ? I really want to se a proper solution so I can understand better the reasoning at hand..

$y' = 5y +4z $

$z'=-4y -3z$

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703369/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-system/703424#703424) you can see a fully worked out example. If you post your work, people can help you better.

Comment: I'm not good with LaTex so that's why I couldn't post my work so far

Comment: Nope, but that's the only one we studied so far. I'm interested in any method that would yield a correct result

Comment: Another method, if you know about matrix exponential, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744296/differential-equations-diagonalizable-matrix/744324#744324) helps.

Comment: You need to force yourself to post stuff using $\LaTeX$, before you know it you'll be proficient. This will help you save time in the long run as it will allow you to get quicker answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Substitute the first equation in the second

$$ z' = -4y -\frac{3}{4}(y'-5y)$$

Yet, from the first equation

$$z' = \frac{1}{4}(y'' - 5y')$$.

Comment: I arrived at $y''-2y'+y=0$ which yields $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^xx$.. But Wolfram comes with quite a different solution when solving the system...

Comment: @jaynick, Did you mean $y''-2y'+y =0$?

Comment: Yep, sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: @jaynick, Are you sure? I have tested it in Wolfram and it has given me  your solution.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D5y%2B4z+%3B+z%27%3D-4y-3z Well, their form of $y(x)$ looks quite different from the one I arrived at..

Comment: @jaynick, it's the same: $y = c_1e^x(4x+1) + 4c_2(e^x x) = c_1e^x + (4c_1+4c_2)e^x x = c_1e^x + c_3e^x x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Add both equations:

$$y'+z'=y+z\quad\Longrightarrow\quad y+z=ce^t$$

Now substitute.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is more difficult than i thought because the coefficient matrix has a repeating root. i need a little set up first. let $x$ be a two dimensional column vector and $A$ a $2 \times 2$ real matrix. consider the linear differential equation
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$$

first we establish that:

(a)  if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $x_0 \neq 0$ is a corresponding eigenvector    pf $A,$  then  $x = x_0e^{\lambda t}$ is a solution.

(b) if $x_1 \neq 0$ is such that $(A - \lambda)^2x_1 = 0, (A-\lambda)x_1 = x_0 \neq 0,$ then $x = x_0 te^{\lambda t} + x_1 e^t$ is a solution. (a way to see this is to assume that $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda \pm \epsilon.$ by (a) 
$x_0(e^{\lambda t + \epsilon t} -   e^{\lambda t - \epsilon t}) /{ 2 \epsilon} = x_0te^{\lambda t}$)

in your case $$ A= \pmatrix{5 & 4\\-4 & -3}$$ the eigenvalues of $A$ are given by 
$$det(A- \lambda I) = det \pmatrix{5 - \lambda & 4\\-4 & -3 - \lambda} = (\lambda - 1)^2$$ we will pick $$x_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}, x_0 = \pmatrix{4 \\ -4}$$

the two linearly independent solutions of $\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ is 
$$\left\{ \pmatrix{1 \\-1}e^t, \pmatrix{4t+1\\-4t}e^t \right\} $$